# В чем ошибка при распарсивании?

Tags: java, android, json

JSstr - строка JSON. AndroidStudio ругается на строку js_sites.getJSONObject(k); подчеркивая красным "k". говорит тип д.б. String

```
        JSONObject strJS = null;
        strJS = new JSONObject(JSstr);
        JSONObject js_sites = strJS.getJSONObject("sites"); 
        for (int k=0;k<js_sites.length();k++) {
          JSONObject temp = js_sites.getJSONObject(k);
          Arr_name[k] = temp.getString("name");
```

Мне надо перебрать весь массив
{"name" : "one"}
{"name" : "two"}
{"name" : ...}...]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте так:

```
    JSONObject strJS = null;
    strJS = new JSONObject(JSstr);
    JSONArray js_sites = strJS.getJSONArray("sites"); 
        for (int k=0; k<js_sites.length(); k++) {
             JSONObject temp = js_sites.getJSONObject(k);
             Arr_name[k] = temp.getString("name");
         }
```

Comment: Благодарю! Ошибка исчезла.